# Call a method from constructed string in Ruby / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I've got a problem in doing some metaprogramming in Ruby / Rails which must be minor, but I can't get the clue.

I wan't to assign values to an active record relation, with my model having attributes:

```
MyModelClass.p1_id,
            .p2_id,
            ...
            .p8_id

SecondModel.position #Integer in (1..8)
```

I now want to do the following

```
sms = SecondModel.where(:xyz => 'bla')

sms.each do |sm|
  mmc = MyModellClass.first
  mmc.#somehow construct method here = sm.id
end
```

So that somehow this is accomplished

```
mmc.p1_id = sm.id
mmc.p2_id = sm.id
..
mmc.p8_id = sm.id
```

To sum up: I want to create that p*n*_id stuff dynamically, but I can't find out, how to tell Ruby, that this should be a method. I tried so far:

```
mmc.send('p#{sm.position.to_s}_id'.to_sym) = sm.id
```

But this doesn't work. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. Try this:

```
mmc.send("p#{sm.position.to_s}_id=", sm.id)
```

Here we call the method with `=` and pass the value of attribute as the second argument of `send`

Comment: Thanks a lot, as I supposed: Easy solution, but I simply didn't get it.